# Unconditional State Change

Tags: solidity

Can I force making changes to the value of variables not paying attention to `require` statement?
For example, I have the next code:

```
contract_runs = contract_runs + 1;
success = exchange();
require(success);
```

I want changes initiated by the `exchange` function to be applied only if `success` is `true` but increase `contract_runs` regardless of the value of this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use try/catch if `exchange` is in another contract.

```
try anotherContract.exchange() {
  // succeeded
}
catch (bytes memory err) {
  // failed
}
```

If it is in the same contract you could use `this.exchange()` just be aware that it will change msg.sender and requires exchange to be public or external.